# Запуск Vue JS подключением скрипта на локальном компьютере

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет! У меня есть небольшое приложение на Vue JS, одна страничка. Сделал подключение Vue, axios, locale через script вот так:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/umd/locale/ru-RU.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.js"></script>
```

При запуске приложения я вижу, что идут запросы на скачивание этих скриптов из интернета.
Сейчас возникла необходимость интернационализации. Это значит добавится еще скрипт для VueI18n и несколько скриптов для других языков.
Можно ли как то подключать эти скрипты не из интернета, а скачать их, положить в проект и импортировать?
Я попробовал скачать, создал папку и положил их туда, потом подключал вот так:

```
<script src="..js/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="..js/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/umd/locale/ru-RU.js"></script>
<script src="..js/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.js"></script>
```

Но это не сработало

**Обновление 1**

Начал экспериментировать с путями к файлам. Файловая структура проекта на скрине[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Варианты прописания путей которые я попробовал:

```
<script src="scripts/vue.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/app/scripts/vue.js"></script>
<script src="../app/scripts/vue.js"></script>
```

Каждый раз при запуске приложение пытается загрузить мой скрипт по адресу `https://мой-домен.com/api/v1/app/scripts/vue.js` и естественно получает 404 ошибку так как у меня такой маршрут не прописан

Comment: Можете заскринить файловую структуру проекта? Хотелось бы понять, правильно ли прописывается путь к этим ффайлам

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли как то подключать эти скрипты не из интернета, а скачать их,
> положить в проект и импортировать?

Да, файлы можно разместить на своем сервере и подключить к документу.
Для этого должно быть достаточно изучения правил составления относительных ссылок (URI)... то есть, чтения и понимания **[RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3)**.

> Но это не сработало

В данном случае, ссылки скорее всего некорректны, т.к. вместо папки `..js/` вероятно подразумевалась папка js уровнем выше (`../js/`), то есть:

```
<script src="../js/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="../js/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/umd/locale/ru-RU.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.js"></script>
```

---

Но тут сразу стоит упомянуть, что в правильном подключении ресурсов из CDN, нет абсолютно ничего плохого. И более того: для посетителей, такой вариант зачастую лучше - если на разных сайтах ассеты  подключены по одинаковым ссылкам, то они кэшируются браузером, и это значительно ускоряет загрузку страниц.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновление вопроса

Comment: @Петр, так суть ответа не меняется от обновления. Суть: ***поможет указание правильных ссылок, и это достигается пониманием написанного в спецификации URI***. Из вопроса неясно, каким местом он вообще относится к Vue (единственной метке), и где же у тебя находится документ рут... если корень `app/`, то пути должны быть относительно корня, т.е. вида `src="/scripts/vue.js"`. А если в другой папке - то соотв. и пути будут другие. Ну что еще тут можно сказать?))

Comment: на сервере полный путь к моим скриптам такой `/app/app/scripts/vue.js`. Однако это никак не решает проблему, я методом перебора уже все возможные варианты попробовал и каждый раз идет get запрос на получение скрипта. Я понимаю получал бы я ошибку типа файл не найден по указанному пути или что то в этом роде, но я получаю 404 на get запрос

Comment: @Петр, а какое отношение имеет _полный путь на сервере_ к написанному мной?

Comment: @Петр, _"получал бы я ошибку типа файл не найден (...), но я получаю 404 на get запрос"_ - код серверного ответа 404 и означает, что ресурс по указанному пути не найден.